# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for a model function

Tags: python

I had a script to fit the experimental data to a model, it works fine so far so good and the only problem occurs when I tried to print out the fitting results.

What is the failure that I made?

```
par = ['a', 'u', 'e', 'w', 'h', 'b', 'c1', 'p', 'd']

# parameters 
a = 20      
u = 4          
e = 2.84            
w = 0.047        
h = 0.10       
b = 0.1            
# structural parameters
c1 = 1.4          
p = 50      
d = 4.3  

pars_bounds=([-np.inf,-np.inf,2.84, -np.inf,-np.inf,-np.inf, -np.inf, -np.inf, 4.3],\
                    [np.inf,np.inf,3, np.inf,np.inf,np.inf, np.inf, np.inf,6])

pars = (a, u, e, w, h, b, c1, p, d)
                
rslt, err = curve_fit(guass_FP, x, y, pars , bounds = pars_bounds) 
pars_err = np.sqrt(np.diag(err))
err = pars_err.round(5) 
rslt = rslt.round(4) 

# print fit parameters and uncertainties
for v, p in enumerate(par):
    p = p +": {0} \u00B1 {1}".format(rslt[v], err[v])
    print(p)
```

Output:

```
a: 21.1449 ± 3.11362
u: 4.6946 ± 0.01288
e: 2.844 ± 9e-05
w: 0.0384 ± 0.00012
h: 0.1967 ± 0.00233
b: 0.0 ± 0.00249
c1: 1.4 ± 0.0
p: 50.0 ± 0.0
d: 4.3 ± 0.0

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "FP_fit.py", line 152, in <module>
    plt.plot(x,guass_FP(x, *pars), 'b--', label='guess', linewidth=1.0)
  File "FP_fit.py", line 62, in guass_FP
    m = Fabry_Perot(x)
  File "FP_fit.py", line 46, in Fabry_Perot
    fp = (1+(R23**2+2*R23*cos(4*pi*n_gn*(d*1000-p)/x))) /(1+(R21**2*R23**2-2*abs(c1)*R21*R23*cos(4*pi*n_gn*(d*1000-p)/x)))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'str'
```

Comment: Could you add the definition of `guass_FP`? Regardless, you've problem with printing because using string formatting on presumably what are floats eg `p`.

Comment: `p` is a string in `d*1000-p`. You didn't include the code that raised the error, but it's likely that this is because you assign a string to `p` in the last `for` loop.

Comment: thanks for a quick response, that is exactly what I did wrong, I assigned 'p' in the loop, which is a parameter in the function.  It works fine now. Thanks again.

Comment: How can you simultaneously get normal output and an error message? The error message doesn't seem to be related to the code you have shown.

Comment: is this sympy code? please include your import statements. Or just the full code. I can't debug if I can't even run the code.

Comment: Probably just casting it to `str` would solve, as `print(str(p) +": {0} \u00B1 {1}".format(rslt[v], err[v]))` though you could add to formatting:
`"{0}: {1} \u00B1 {2}".format(p, rslt[v], err[v])`

Comment: As @ Brian  mentioned above, I carelessly assigned p in the loop which is also previously used as an variable in the function definition.  So  p takes a string value from the loop and feeds to the function in ``plt.plot(x,guass_FP(x, *pars), 'b--', label='guess', linewidth=1.0) `` section. As a consequence, I got error messages like this "The “TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'”  "".